# Handling events of forms

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I am trying to make a form I wrote this simple form

```
 class Profile extends React.Component {  
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: '', age:''};
    
        this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleAgeChange = this.handleAgeChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }
    
      
      handleNameChange(event) {
        this.setState({name: event.target.name});
      }
    
      handleAgeChange(event) {
        this.setState({age: event.target.age});
      }
    
      handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('Name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        alert('Age was submitted: '+  this.state.age);
    
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
            </label>
    
            <label>
              Age:
              <input type="text" value={this.state.age}  onChange={this.handleAgeChange}/>
            </label>
    
    
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        );
      }
    }
export default Profile;
```

When I try it I can't write anything in the Name and the alert always shows me 'Name was submitted: undefined' 'Age was submitted: undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few typos in your code.  For each of your `handleChange` functions, you should have `event.target.value` for the state value being set instead of the names of the fields.

Also in your `alert` function for the name, the value should be `this.state.name` instead of `this.state.value`.

Here is a complete working version:

```js
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: "", age: "" };

    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleAgeChange = this.handleAgeChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  handleAgeChange(event) {
    this.setState({ age: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("Name was submitted: " + this.state.name);
    alert("Age was submitted: " + this.state.age);

    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleNameChange}
          />
        </label>

        <label>
          Age:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleAgeChange}
          />
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Profile / > ,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```